# MySQL - delay between store procedures

Tags: mysql, delay, sleep

I have a procedure that is taking between 2 - 5 minutes to execute. I wish to run it all the time with 1 minute delay between the executions.

I been trying to create event from procedure, but it's forbidden starting from MySQL 5.3.

Is there any way to this from MySQL or I need to code for it?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Q1: Why is this procedure taking so long to run?

Comment: Seems like you need to optimise the query that you are running. Assuming it is not optimal already. Please add query and explain statement output to question so we can try help.

Comment: @Namphibian My query is optimal already. This is not what the question is about. I did not add it here because it irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that '**Event Scheduler**' is disabled from Mysql 5.3 onwards? From which source you got that info?

Why i asked because i can see the [**Create event**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html) section in official Mysql 5.5 documentation.

Have noticed the below example also in the Mysql 5.5 documentation page.

```
CREATE EVENT e_call_myproc
    ON SCHEDULE
      AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    DO CALL myproc(5, 27);
```

Comment: Sorry but it's now. You can create event that will call a procedure, no problem with that. But you cannot create event inside a procedure.